# Dynamically change Prefab rendered when using image tracking in Unity ARFoundation

Tags: unity-game-engine, augmented-reality, ar-foundation

(Newbie to Unity here)
I have a UI button that when I press it and based on an if condition, I want to change the prefab that is being rendered on the detected marker.
The function called when clicking the UI button is this:

```
public void SwitchScenes() {

    if (modeButtonImage.sprite == sensorSprite)
    {
        imageManager.trackedImagePrefab = actuatorPrefab;
    }
    else
    {
        imageManager.trackedImagePrefab = sensorPrefab;
    }

}
```

This code is attached to the AROrigin GameObject and it is not working for my purpose.

PS.
I have check that the `imageManager` field and is correctly initialized and its type is `ARTrackedImageManager`. I also have checked that the if statements are executed correctly, and they do